# Random Sample of Bernoulli distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose we have a random sample from Bernoulli(p) distribution of size n

let $~~~~Y_1=X_1+X_2$ then $Y_1$~  $b(2,p)$ exact distribution

let $Y_2 = (X_1+X_2)/2$. Is $Y_2$~$b(2,p)$ exact distribution?

Comment: What do you mean, "same mean"? $\mathbb{E}[Y_1]= \mathbb{E}[X_1]+\mathbb{E}[X_2] = 2p$.

Comment: oh. I think I was confused. I see so, Y1~b(2,2p) and Y2~b(2,p). thank you

Comment: No, not that either. If by b you mean Binomial, then Y1 is b(2,p), and Y2 is not a binomial.

Comment: so, Is Y2~b(2,p), because I know X1+.....Xn ~b(n.p). but not sure (X1+.....Xn)/n ~b(n,p)

Comment: No, because you divide by 2. As said above, Y2 is not binomially distributed.

Comment: thanks. how can I find the exact distribution any hint?

Comment: For $Y_2$ see that the only possible values $Y_2$ can take are $0, 0.5,$ and $1$. To find the exact distribution you could draw out a table showing each possible outcome of $Y_2$ and the resulting probabilities of each outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a straight transformation to check this.

Let $X$ ~ $(2,p)$, and let $Y = \frac{X}{2}$. Suppose $0 < p < 1$. Then the pmf for $X$ is $${{2}\choose{x}} p^x (1-p)^{2-x}, x = 0, 1, 2$$ and $0$ otherwise.

Since $Y = \frac{X}{2}$, $X = 2Y$. $0 < p < 1$ here as well. Substituting $2y$ in for $x$ and adding the appropriate support gets the pmf for $Y$:

$$ {{2}\choose{2y}} p^{2y} (1-p)^{2-2y}, y = 0, 0.5, 1$$ and $0$ otherwise.

It is easy to see that these pmfs are not the same. Just compare $p_x(1)$ and $p_y(1)$. So $X$ and $Y$ can't have the same distribution, since pmfs uniquely determine the distribution of a discrete random variable.